# Search RTF for Bold font

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf

In my app I sort through thousands of lines of questions to create a property list file. As part of this, I need it to detect which texts are in bold, as those are the ones marked as the correct answer. It would be something like

```
1. What is 1+1?
A. 2
B. 3
C. 4
D. 5
```

And in this case, A. 2 would be BOLD. What I'm having issues with is detecting the bold text to easily load all the correct answers. What I am trying so far returns absolutely nothing.

I simply drag the RTF into the sidebar in Xcode to make sure it is accessible. It is, and everything in this code runs fine, except for trying to find the bold text:

```
-(void)editTextFile {
    NSError *error = nil;
      NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2024ROMANSEDITED" ofType:@"rtf"];
      NSAttributedString *fileContent = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
      
      NSArray *questionItems = [fileContent.string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];
      
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
      NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"chatgptoptions.plist"];
      
      NSMutableArray *questions = [NSMutableArray array];
      
      for (NSString *questionItem in questionItems) {
          NSArray *items = [questionItem componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
          NSString *theQuestion = items.firstObject;
          NSArray *answerOptions = [items subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, items.count - 1)];
          
          NSString *correctAnswerIndex = @"";
          
          for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < answerOptions.count; i++) {
              NSString *answerOption = answerOptions[i];
              
              NSRegularExpression *boldRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<b>(.*?)<\\/b>"
                                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                           error:nil];
              NSArray *boldMatches = [boldRegex matchesInString:answerOption
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, answerOption.length)];
              
              if (boldMatches.count > 0) {
                  correctAnswerIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", i];
                  break;
              }
          }
          
          NSDictionary *innerDict = @{
              @"Answer": correctAnswerIndex,
              @"duration_in_seconds": @"30",
              @"negative_points": @"5",
              @"options": answerOptions,
              @"points": @"20",
              @"question": theQuestion,
              @"question_type": @"1"
          };
          
          [questions addObject:innerDict];
      }
      
      NSDictionary *plistDictionary = @{
          @"Questions": questions
      };
      
      BOOL success = [plistDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
      
      if (success) {
          NSLog(@"PLIST file generated successfully at path: %@", plistPath);
      } else {
          NSLog(@"Failed to generate PLIST file.");
      }
  }
```

In this scenario I would expect correctAnswerIndex to give me an NSString of "0", but instead I get nothing. Any ideas?

Update 2:
Trying to keep all the data, but font family keeps coming back as null, so I seem to be losing it somewhere.

```
 -(void)editTextFile {
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2024ROMANSEDITED" ofType:@"rtf"];
    NSError *error = nil;
     NSAttributedString *fileContent = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
     
     NSArray *questionItems = [self extractQuestionItemsFromRTFFileContent:fileContent];
     
     NSMutableArray *questions = [NSMutableArray array];
     
     for (NSAttributedString *questionItem in questionItems) {
         NSString *theQuestion = [self extractQuestionFromQuestionItem:questionItem];
         NSArray *answerOptions = [self extractAnswerOptionsFromQuestionItem:questionItem];
         NSString *correctAnswerIndex = [self extractCorrectAnswerIndexFromAnswerOptions:answerOptions];
         
         NSDictionary *innerDict = @{
             @"Answer": correctAnswerIndex,
             @"duration_in_seconds": @"30",
             @"negative_points": @"5",
             @"options": answerOptions,
             @"points": @"20",
             @"question": theQuestion,
             @"question_type": @"1"
         };
         
         [questions addObject:innerDict];
     }
     
     NSDictionary *plistDictionary = @{
         @"Questions": questions
     };
     
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
     NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"chatgptoptions.plist"];
     
     BOOL success = [plistDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
     
     if (success) {
         NSLog(@"PLIST file generated successfully at path: %@", plistPath);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Failed to generate PLIST file.");
     }
 }

 - (NSArray *)extractQuestionItemsFromRTFFileContent:(NSAttributedString *)fileContent {
     NSMutableArray *questionItems = [NSMutableArray array];
     NSArray *paragraphs = [fileContent.string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];
     
     for (NSString *paragraph in paragraphs) {
         NSAttributedString *attributedParagraph = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:paragraph];
         [questionItems addObject:attributedParagraph];
     }
     
     return questionItems;
 }

 - (NSString *)extractQuestionFromQuestionItem:(NSAttributedString *)questionItem {
     return questionItem.string;
 }

 - (NSArray *)extractAnswerOptionsFromQuestionItem:(NSAttributedString *)questionItem {
     NSString *questionText = questionItem.string;
     NSArray *lines = [questionText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
     return [lines subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, lines.count - 1)];
 }

 - (NSString *)extractCorrectAnswerIndexFromAnswerOptions:(NSArray *)answerOptions {
     for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < answerOptions.count; i++) {
         NSString *answerOption = answerOptions[i];
         if ([self isAnswerOptionBold:answerOption]) {
             return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", i];
         }
     }
     return @"";
 }

- (BOOL)isAnswerOptionBold:(NSString *)answerOption {
    NSAttributedString *attributedOption = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:answerOption];
    
    NSRange effectiveRange;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [attributedOption attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:&effectiveRange];
    UIFont *font = attributes[NSFontAttributeName];
    NSDictionary *fontAttributes = [font.fontDescriptor fontAttributes];
    NSString *fontFamilyName = fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute];
    UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits traits = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
    BOOL isFontBold = (traits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) == UIFontDescriptorTraitBold;
    
    NSLog(@"Font Family: %@", fontFamilyName);
    NSLog(@"Is Bold: %@", isFontBold ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    if (font) {
        NSDictionary *fontAttributes = [font.fontDescriptor fontAttributes];
        NSString *fontFamilyName = fontAttributes[UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute];
        UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits traits = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits;
        BOOL isFontBold = (traits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) == UIFontDescriptorTraitBold;
        
        NSLog(@"Font Family: %@", fontFamilyName);
        NSLog(@"Is Bold: %@", isFontBold ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        
        if (isFontBold) {
            NSLog(@"Bold: %@", answerOption);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Now the question is why is the bold text not being represented in the rtf

Comment: It’s definitely bold in preview, TextEdit, and even when I see it in Xcode as a preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have the RTF string as `NSAttributedString` you can [enumerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute?language=objc) the attributed string to get all ranges of the `bold` parts.

And I recommend to use the URL related API of `NSBundle`

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"2024ROMANSEDITED" withExtension:@"rtf"];

NSAttributedString *fileContent = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithURL: fileURL options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error: &error];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
[fileContent enumerateAttribute: NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, fileContent.length) options: 0 usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (([[(UIFont *)value fontDescriptor] symbolicTraits] & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold) != 0) {
        [result addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange: range]];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

`result` contains the ranges wrapped in `NSValue` objects.

Comment: I tried this out and the NSLog came back with an empty array

Comment: I tested the code successfully with a sample RTF file. May something is wrong with your RTF data.

Comment: I have the attributed string with all the font data, but I guess it isn't finding anything when it enumerates, but I can verify even looking at the RTF file in Xcode that it is bolded